# Unable to get all desired info

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im currently building an app to list all the background processes in the iPhone via the UITableView. However, it is only listing the last processID and processName successfully.

The method for getting the process info is stored in the viewDidLoad method, and looks like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
size_t miblen = 4;

size_t size;
int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

do {

    size += size / 10;
    newprocess = realloc(process, size);

    if (!newprocess){

        if (process){
            free(process);
        }


    }

    process = newprocess;
    st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

} while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

if (st == 0){

    if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0){
        int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

        if (nprocess){

            NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--){


                NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];
                NSString * combinedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", processID, @"           " ,processName];

                NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName, nil]
                                                                    forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProcessID", @"ProcessName", nil]];




                    arryData =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", combinedString], nil];





                //For debugging purposes
                NSLog(@"%@", dict);


                [processID release];
                [processName release];
                [array addObject:dict];
                [dict release];
            }

            free(process);
            return [array autorelease];
        }
    }
}



[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

My table method looks like this :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [arryData count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return @"Process ID              Process Name";
}



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


// Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue= [arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.text = cellValue;
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
@end
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `arryData` to a new array on every iteration of your for loop. There's no way `arryData` could contain more than one element. Also you're probably leaking all but the last of those arrays.

Comment: So how can I go about doing that? Sorry I'm new to Objective C.

Comment: Create an NSMutableArray prior to that for loop and add items to it on every iteration instead of replacing an array containing one element with a new array containing one other element.